# Implementing Model View Controler pattern to a Desktop application with multiple Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller

I am learning he MVC pattern and I applied it in a few simple Demo Apps in WPF and WinForms which had a one View or Window.

```
        App app = new App();
        app.MainWindow = new MainWindow();

        IModelInterface model = new ModelCalculator();
        IControllerInterface controler = new ControllerCalculator(model);
        app.Run();
```

I know that many would suggest that I should use MVVM, and I will, but I am curious how to do this with MVC.

**My Question** is how to manage multiple Views (for example: a *Menu* with many *Menu Items*). Every *Menu Item* would be a Window with its own buttons text boxes and so forth, and they would need its own *Controller*?

Or do I just put everything in one *Controller* ?

This is the `IControlerInterface` and `ControlerCalculator` class.

```
public interface IControllerInterface
{

    void Addition();
    void Divide();
    void Multiply();
    void Subtract();
    void Equals();
    void RemoveNull();
    void Clear();

    void OpenChildWindow();
}

class ControllerCalculator : IControllerInterface
{
    IModelInterface model; 

    MainWindow view;

    public ControllerCalculator(IModelInterface model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        view = new MainWindow(this,model);
        view.Show();
    }

    #region ControlerMethodsRegion

    public void Addition() 
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(view.txtDisplyValue.Text);
        model.SetInput(number);
        view.txtDisplyValue.Clear();
        view.txtDisplyValue.Text = "0";
        model.SetState(States.Add);
    }

    public void Subtract()
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(view.txtDisplyValue.Text);
        model.SetInput(number);
        view.txtDisplyValue.Clear();
        view.txtDisplyValue.Text = "0";
        model.SetState(States.Subtract);
    }
}
```

I assume that putting everything in one Controller is not the solution since I would need to change the interface, because the View uses it to call Controller.

So any idea how to manage a `MenuItem` click from the `MainWindow` which is my main View ?

Comment: You've tagged your question with both `WPF` and `winforms`. Which one are you building your application in?

Comment: MVC doesn't necessarily mean you cannot leverage the binding capability of WPF. you "could" use your Controllers or Models as binding sources and this would help to keep your code cleaner.

Comment: Sorry in this example i used WPF

Comment: According to original MVC definition, each view should should have a controller which services it. I would recommend for you do dig into the mentioned [publication](http://www.itu.dk/courses/VOP/E2005/VOP2005E/8_mvc_krasner_and_pope.pdf) and M.Fowler's [article](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) on the subject.

Comment: I do not recommend MVC for WPF (or WinForms for that matter). Use MVVM for WPF and MVP for WinForms.

Comment: Ok I will read those articles :) Thanks a lot